# how to make an arc rotating around a center in ExtendScript After Effects?

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects, ecmascript-3

I want to make a loading animation in After Effects using scripts

I get no arc only white screen with shape layer there

and this is what gets rendered in the app
[image]

This is my code that doesn't work

```js
app.project.close(CloseOptions.DO_NOT_SAVE_CHANGES);
app.newProject();
app.beginUndoGroup("Create Comp");

// Create a new composition with a solid layer
var comp = app.project.items.addComp("My Composition", 1920, 1080, 1, 10, 24);

comp.openInViewer();

var solid = comp.layers.addSolid([1, 1, 1], "My Solid", 1920, 1080, 1, 10);

// Create a new shape layer
var shapeLayer = comp.layers.addShape();
// shapeLayer.moveToStart();
shapeLayer.enabled= true;

// Set position of the shape layer
var shapePosition = shapeLayer.property("ADBE Transform Group").property("ADBE Position");
shapePosition.setValue([960,540]);

var path = shapeLayer.property("ADBE Root Vectors Group").addProperty("ADBE Vector Shape - Group");
// make a arc
path.property("ADBE Vector Shape").setValue(new Shape());
path.property("ADBE Vector Shape").value.vertices = [[0, 0], [100, 100], [200, 0]];
path.property("ADBE Vector Shape").value.inTangents = [[-50, -50], [0, 0]];
path.property("ADBE Vector Shape").value.outTangents = [[0, 0], [50, 50]];
path.property("ADBE Vector Shape").value.closed = true;
path.enabled = true;

var stroke = shapeLayer.property("ADBE Root Vectors Group").addProperty("ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke");
stroke.property("ADBE Vector Stroke Width").setValue(5);
stroke.property("ADBE Vector Stroke Color").setValue([1, 0, 0]);
stroke.enabled = true;

var fill = shapeLayer.property("ADBE Root Vectors Group").addProperty("ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill");
fill.property("ADBE Vector Fill Color").setValue([1, 0, 0]);
fill.enabled = true;

// Create an animation for the rotation property
var rotation = shapeLayer.property("ADBE Transform Group").property("ADBE Rotate Z");
rotation.setValueAtTime(0, 0);
rotation.setValueAtTime(5, 180);

// Set the composition duration to 10 seconds
comp.duration = 10;

app.endUndoGroup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties in AE can't be set by assigning values to them. You need to use the `setValue()` method. Additionally in this instance you want to set the values of the `shape` object *before* assigning it to the `path` property.

```
var theShape = new Shape();
theShape.vertices = [[0, 0], [100, 100], [200, 0]];
theShape.inTangents = [[-50, -50], [0, 0]];
theShape.outTangents = [[0, 0], [50, 50]];
theShape.closed = true;
path.property("ADBE Vector Shape").setValue(theShape);
```

Also, as an AE developer: [image]